# Apache Phoenix 5.x with Pyspark 3.x

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jar, apache-phoenix

Has anyone ever setup Aapache Phoenix 5.x with Pyspark 3.x. I can't configure pyspark for a task where I would write data with spark to phoenix.

```
flattened_df.write \
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("table", phoenix_table) \
  .option("zkUrl", zookeeper_url) \
  .save()
```

I get an error sayning:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o227.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(java.lang.Object[])'

Tried adding spark-phoenix jar, phoenix client jar but could not get it to work